# Ads are showing sometimes but sometimes not

Tags: android, ads

I have an app in playstore. The app contains two ads(Banner and 
Interstitial). The app published almost 2 months ago. Test ads work fine. Ads were working well in the early days. But now real ads are showing sometimes but sometimes not showing. I'm checking the app many times in the day(Never clicked ads). I couldn't find any problem like this when i search at internet. What can be the problem ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are receiving testing ads, but not real ads, then your implementation for ads is all okay.

Admob is very poor in providing ads. So I suggest you to add other ads networks too if one of network is failed to provide ads.(E.g. Facebook, StartApp, AppLovin etc.)

Comment: I just read your comment now ! Is there a guide or youtube video to add other companies ads to our android application?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my flashlight app. I tried a lot of things but nothing worked, test ads were working fine but my real ads worked for a couple of days and then suddenly stopped. There was no suspension or anything like that so I tried to contact google AdMob, but no useful info was provided from them. I was desperate and i wanted to ditch the google ads and try different ad networks. Then by a lucky chance, i contacted a developer who helped me with this issue. The problem was in the addition of two permissions Internet and Access Network State to the manifest file of my project. When i added this, ads started to show on my device only, but not on other devices. I also needed to define my ad activity in the manifest file and properly implement my banner ad at the bottom of my constraint layout. Only after that everything worked fine. So sometimes the problem can be in the implementation itself.

Add these permissions and activity to the manifest(if they are not already present):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<activity
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout
 |uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

If you are using constraint layout and banner ad, add this to your XML layout file and adjust the position of this AdView to your liking(bottom or top of the layout) and replace test ad unit id with your real id.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/adView_banner"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
  ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
  ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

It's important that you don't forget to add

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

attribute for the AdView.

With these changes update the version of your app on Play Store. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of no-fill. Which happens under a lot of criteria, let's name a very few of them

- You are not under any Advertiser's targeted audience.
- You have reached max frequency cap for day/hour.
- For the particular user, the ad network has shown all the available ads via other apps

etc.

So when an ad server doesn't return an ad for ad request that is called no-fill. You can check the fill rate on the dashboard of the ad network.

I would suggest you to ad mediation like MoPub, AerServ. What it does is that if the first ad network can't fill the ad request then they will get an ad from next one and so on.

Comment: https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/integrate/

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that it was the device that I was using. While using test ads on development for some reason that particular device is stuck in test mode itself (or it might be because of the same google account that I used to test the ads). So try installing the app on different devices other than emulators and the devices that you use to test.

Even if admob account is activated it still took around a couple of days for me to get the real ads.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @simpleCoder worked for me perfecly fine

This is what I've added to my code:

Andriod.Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<activity
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout
 |uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

build.gradle.kts (:app):
overwrite the buildTypes/add the two boolean in release..

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true // was false until 28.10.
            isShrinkResources = true //new 28.10. -> both on true saves installsize alot
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
```

Hope its working for you as well!